# socket.io calling emit from object method not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

In my socket.io game, I have a file `bot.js` containing a class `BotPlayer` which will play with a human player if another human player is unavailable. I want the bot to have a method `makeMove` which will emit its moves to the human player. I know the makeMove method is being executed, but I can't get the emit() function to fire.

bot.js:

```
var BotPlayer = function (partner) {
    this.partner = partner;
    ...
    this.submitScore = function(score) {
        console.log('SUBMIT_SCORE')
        module.exports = function (io) {
        this.partner.emit('message', {message: this.username + "'s score:   " + score})
            }
    };

exports.BotPlayer = BotPlayer
```

socket.js:

```
var Bot = require('../bot/bot');
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
client.on('botPlay', function (user) {
var botPlayer = new Bot.BotPlayer(client);

client.emit('message', {message: "You have joined a game with " + botPlayer.username + "!"})
client.emit('start');
 botPlayer.play();
}
```

}

In my main node.js file, I have:

```
// socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
require('./routes/socket.js')(io);
```

And if I add to that:

```
require('./bot/bot.js')(io);
```

I get `TypeError: object is not a function`

Then, if I wrap the entirety of bot.js in:

```
module.exports = function (io) {...};
```

I seem to be unable to export the BotPlayer class, and get:

```
ReferenceError: BotPlayer is not defined
```

How can I implement an emit function within a BotPlayer method
which can communicate with its 'partner', the client?

EDIT: At jfriend00's request, here is the complete code for the files in question:

http://pastebin.com/3MMscP9j

http://pastebin.com/5QXs36HT

http://pastebin.com/nWJ4rQfD

Comment: You mention a lot of different errors, but don't show us enough of your overall context to know why those errors are created.  All you need your `bot` to be is an `eventEmitter`.  Then, you can `.emit()` to it and others can `.on()` to it.  For example, you have errors when using `client`, but you don't even shows us what that is or how it was created.  You need to show a LARGER context so we can actually follow why you might be getting an error.  Not just a bunch of tiny snippets of code that don't let us see what is going on.

Comment: Honestly I believe these to be the pertinent pieces of code though I did edit to show where client comes from. I'm sure you know better than me, so if you can think of what else I should include here please let me know

Comment: You need to do just `exports = BotPlayer` not `exports.BotPlayer = BotPlayer`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin - not necessarily.  They are doing `var botPlayer = new Bot.BotPlayer(client); `.  So, the code is being consistent with the `.BotPlayer` property.

Comment: I added a few more details but as im new to this/ have been staring at this for hours i can quite see what else to put in without the whole file which i fear will be too much and confusing. I really appreciare your input

Comment: If you still want to work on this some more, I think you'll have to show us your entire code files so we can see the overall structure to understand more about what is happening.  You can link to an external site (like GitHub) that has the larger files.

Comment: I have included links to the complete code for the files in question. Thanks